# Jenkins: Using validateButton on a class without Descriptor

Tags: java, jenkins, jelly

I have a `hudson.model.ManagementLink` (which creates a page which can be accessed via *Manage Jenkins*.

I have some form fields which I'd like to validate using the `f:validateButton`. If this were to be done on say the `config.jelly` page of a `Publisher` (which has a descriptor) a simple `doXXX()` method would work in the descriptor.

If I add a similar `doXXX()` method directly to `hudson.model.ManagementLink` it is in fact accessible directly via the URL *myPage/myMethod* however the `f:validateButton` just returns a 404 and obviously I need to send the form values.

One potential solution I've come accross is [withCustomDescriptorByName](https://jenkins-ci.org/maven-site/jenkins-core/jelly-taglib-ref.html#form%3awithCustomDescriptorByName) and have the logic in a descriptor I have elsewhere, *but I can't get that to work*.

Comment: Similarly I need a button on one of my Summary Actions which will do some logic in the background and update the page.

Comment: Just found http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/ValidateButton-without-descriptor-td4409633.html, exploring this now.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: yes I did - I'll post an answer now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the actual question above (i.e. no descriptor), you can supply any fields needed for validation to the `with` attribute of `f:validateButton` (comma separated) then set the `method` attribute to something like the following...

```
method="${it.fullURL}triggerOfficial"
```

... then in the java (`it`) there's a method...

```
public String getFullURL(){
    return Stapler.getCurrentRequest().getOriginalRequestURI().substring(1);
}
```

...then also the method to perform the validation itself...

```
public FormValidation doTriggerOfficial() { 
    return FormValidation.ok("hello");
}
```

---

However, if you want to perform normal field validation (without a validateButton) on a class type which doesn't normally have a descriptor...

1) Add `implements Describable<YourClassName>` to your class signature

2) Add something like this...

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public Descriptor<ConfigLink> getDescriptor() {
    Jenkins jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance();
    if (jenkins == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Jenkins has not been started");
    }
    return jenkins.getDescriptorOrDie(getClass());
}
```

3) Plus an inner class (with the normal `doCheckXXX` methods)

```
@Extension
public static final class DescriptorImpl extends Descriptor<YourClassName> {...}
```

4) Then finally to link it in the jelly add attribute `descriptor="${it.descriptor}"` to the `f:form` tag containing your form elements you want to have auto-validated (this will invoke the `getDescriptor` detailed in step 2)

Comment: I tried to do this with `${it.fullURL}` in `method` attribute of `<f:validateButton>` but it didn't work - button was sending request to the wrong URL: `/descriptorByName/jenkins.model.GlobalPluginConfiguration/<here is what I return from getFullUrl()>`.

Could you please provide some code with `<f:form>`?

Comment: did you implement the getFullURL() as I did? i.e. you can't just return a relative path it must be the full url (which it gets from the stapler).

Comment: unfortunately I can't post code (company policy) - however happy if you paste code and I can see if I can spot anything

Comment: I have the following. `@Extension
public class Plugin extends hudson.Plugin { ... }`. Inside this class there are `getFullURL()` and `doTriggerOfficial()` just as you described. And I have the jelly template with: `<f:validateButton title="Test" progress="Test"
                                      method="${it.fullURL}triggerOfficial" with="username,password"/>`. At my `/configure` page when I press this button, it returns me 404 code: `/descriptorByName/jenkins.model.GlobalPluginConfiguration/configuretriggerOfficial.`.

Comment: I tested something, no matter what I write in `method` attribute of `validateButton`, Jenkins just puts it after `...GlobalPluginConfiguration/`, even if I write something like `http://localhost:8080/`

Comment: ohh right, are you asking about config.jelly? (that's not really what my original post was about) - please can you describe your full problem (i.e. what are you trying to achieve)

Comment: You can see it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35724841/jenkins-validatebutton-in-config-jelly-for-a-class-without-descriptor