# Jenkins: validateButton in config.jelly for a class without Descriptor

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jelly

I have the `Plugin` class without `Descriptor`:

```
@Extension
public class Plugin extends hudson.Plugin {

    // ...

    public FormValidation doValidateForm(String s) {
        return FormValidation.ok("Hello world! Your 's': " + s);
    }
}
```

And I have a `config.jelly` for this class:

```
<?jelly escape-by-default='true'?>
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:f="/lib/form">
    <!-- ... -->
                    <f:entry title="Test">
                        <f:textbox name="test" value="123" field="test"/>
                    </f:entry>
                    <f:validateButton title="Test" progress="Testing..."
                                      method="validateForm" with="test"/>
    <!-- ... -->
</j:jelly>
```

The problem is I can't make Jenkins send request to my method when I press the button. No matter what I write in `method` attribute of `validateButton`, Jenkins just puts it after `/descriptorByName/jenkins.model.GlobalPluginConfiguration/`, even if I write something like `http://localhost:8080/`. How can I connect my `doValidateForm` method and my `validateButton`?

Answer (score 1):

This has to be on the descriptor to get the free functionality.

You also need to annotate your parameters like this

```
FormValidation doCheckServer(@QueryParameter String test) {
    //stuff
}
```

Adding a descriptor is a [simple change](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/My+class+is+missing+descriptor)

```
class Plugin extends AbstractDescribableImpl<Plugin> {
    String test;

    @DataBoundConstructor
    public Plugin(String test) {
        this.test = test; 
    }

    ....

    @Extension
    public static class DescriptorImpl extends Descriptor<Plugin> {
        public String getDisplayName() { return ""; }

        public FormValidation doValidateForm(@QueryParameter String test) {
            return FormValidation.ok("Hello world! Your 'test': " + test);
          }
    }
}
```

Not tested and you will need to do more work to deserialize it from the XML in the job

Comment: Didn't work out. I have a different `DataBoundConstructor` (it saves some other fields, not `test`) but I don't think it's the reason of my problem. `validateButton` still sends request to `/descriptorByName/jenkins.model.GlobalPluginConfiguration/validateForm`.

Comment: If I send request manually to `/descriptorByName/com.my.plugin.Plugin/validateForm` it works as I expect

Comment: it probably can't see it's own descriptor in the config.jelly, the best way to find out is to add `Instance : ${it}` and `Descriptor : ${descriptor}` to somewhere obvious in your config.jelly (which will display as text)

Comment: if your Descriptor comes back blank, try adding a `getDescriptor()` to your class as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23652692 then add attribute `descriptor="${it.descriptor}"` to the outer `j:jelly` tag containing your form elements. If that doesn't work, instead add the `descriptor="${it.descriptor}"` attribute to a new `f:form` element wrapping your form elements.

Comment: @Tom `descriptor` is not empty, it's `jenkins.model.GlobalPluginConfiguration`. But I can set `descriptor` = `${it}` and seems like it could be a way to do what I want. I will try it later. Thanks!

Comment: I checked it out, it worked. I just had to set `$descriptor` to `""` before `validateButton` tag. Than I used method like this: `${rootURL}plugin/$it.PLUGIN_NAME/validateForm`.